# Quickly obtaining an ID to fly within the US

Tags: air-travel, usa, paperwork, identity-cards

I live in Ohio. I am currently in Washington, D.C. I am travelling back to Ohio by air on Sep 2. I have a Ohio state issued driver's license. Unfortunately, I realized now that the license is expiring on Aug 31.

I learned that one cannot travel on an expired license. Adding to this, I am on F-1 visa in the US.

My passport is not with me currently. Is there any way I can get any form of identification to travel on Sep 2nd?

Comment: Get a friend in Ohio to overnight your passport to you.

Comment: see the [TSA site](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/acceptable-ids) for acceptable forms of ID - maybe you have one of these..

Comment: I have already looked at that list. Except passport, I do not have any other id. And I currently do not have my passport with me.

Comment: @Tom I am thinking of that, but I am not sure how to get my friend inside my house without setting off the alarm. Thanks

Comment: Most states will issue a simple ID (it looks like a drivers license, but doesn't grant you the right to drive). I don't know if DC (or a nearby state) can do that on short order, though, but it might be worth looking into. They may require proof of residence within that state/region, though...

Comment: AFAIK, in order to obtain any type of US ID, you need your passport. You can check with the embassy of your home country in Washington, DC, if they can issue you (some kind of) an emergency passport.

Comment: I will say that the agent will almost certainly let you through with a driver's license that's just expired. They may not even notice. It's not guaranteed, and they might point it out to you, but people not having a replacement driver's license for one that just expired happens all the time in the U.S. and is quite understandable (renewals often take too long, etc.), and it's not like the license identifies you that much less 2 days after expiring. You're not using it to drive; just to prove that you are the person named.

Comment: @Flimzy States only issue ID to residents. It sounds like the asker is a resident of Ohio so he can't get DC ID.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: 1) DC isn't a state. 2) Those rules are state-dependant.

Comment: @Flimzy My understanding is that all states issue ID only to residents. Sure, DC isn't a state but I would assume it to be the same unless you have actual evidence to the contrary.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I decided to test your theory, so started through the states alphabetically. The first one, [Alaska](http://doa.alaska.gov/dmv/akol/original.htm), appears to have no residency requirement for state-issued ID cards. Although Alabama does (as does Kansas--my home state)

Comment: @Flimzy Actually Alabama is the alphabetically first but never mind. On the page you link for Alaska, examples of the documents required to prove "residence" include an Alaska voter registration card or an Alaska land deed (not any other state, in both cases). My understanding is that you need to prove that you live in Alaska, not just that live somewhere. Note that it refers to proof of residence, not proof of address. (By analogy, if you were told that you had to prove citizenship to get a US passport, you'd assume they meant US citizenship, rather than French citizenship, right?)

Comment: @DavidRicherby: perhaps, but the fact that the application form accepts addresses in any state (or country) is interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Then you have a problem.**

According to [TSA](http://www.tsa.gov/contact-us):

> Q.  Can I fly with an expired ID?
>
> A.  If you lose your primary ID or it has expired, TSA may accept other forms of ID to help verify your identity.

So if you have to obtain a driver's license to replace your expired one which for [Washington DC](http://dmv.dc.gov/node/152962), [Virginia](http://www.dmv.state.va.us/drivers/#applying.html), or [Maryland](http://www.mva.maryland.gov/drivers/apply/apply.htm) you will be required to provide proof of residence and a passport.  So the only place you can obtain a driver's license now without falsifying records would be Ohio.

So you have several choices:

1. Change your flight from September 2nd to something earlier then August 31st.
2. Rent a car today drive to Ohio and renew your driver's license and drive back. (9 hours pure drive time to Bridgeport, OH and Back from DC)
3. Have someone overnight your passport to you as @Tom has suggested.

Save that you may be out of luck.

Comment: 2nd is probably best as it's always easier to renew a driver's license before it expires than afterwards :)

Comment: Thanks! I knew option 3 is what I would have to do eventually, but wanted to look for any other easier option. As it is clear now, I will make my friend break in to my house somehow :P